# socket.io example not working - Windows

Tags: node.js, windows-7, socket.io

Im using Node.js 0.6.2 on Windows 7

I managed to get the dependencies solved on Win7 for socket io, now when i launch one of the example apps it doesnt throw any errors.

however, for the IP and listener it reports its listening on , when  i launch that in the browser, the connection times out.

Any ideas?

I've tried setting app.listen to different ports and IP addresses, but no luck.

Just for reference, i've tried the famous "hello world" Node.js example which works fine.

Things i've already checked

- Other services running on the same ports or same listener IP
- Different IP addresses and ports
- Firewall / Port blocking
- Restarting of the machine
- dependencies in node_modules
- Different browsers
- Telnetting to the listener port (which shows a response so the listener must be working?)

Comment: Can you run [node_chat](https://github.com/ry/node_chat)? That would guarantee that the problem isn't in your code.

Comment: OK - I first tried node_chat and wasnt able to get it to work.
My command to launch it was 'node node_chat/server.js' but then the browser timed out. When i then changed director to node_chat, it worked fine. So is this a a problem with paths?

I thought i could launch an app from a home directory provided i have the correct path? I presume thats the same problem i have with Socket.io - I'll check

Comment: OK still no luck with Socket.io even when changing directory and launching the app from within the directory.

Comment: Have you tried the hello world http server?

Comment: @alFReDNSH As stated in my original post. The hello world example works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem with some outside help.
I downloaded Node 0.6.3 which comes with NPM.

I created a test folder and then ran `NPM Install socket.io express` within the test folder and then tested the example app from the Socket IO website in the how-to-use section.

Socket IO emitted the events fine and it all seems to be working well. Thanks everyone for the help and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

So this works for me (running msysGit and node.js, both latest versions; both Windows installers):

```
$ cd c:\msysgit\msysgit\cmd
$ git clone git://github.com/ry/node_chat.git
$ cd node_chat
$ "c:\progra~1\nodejs\node.exe" server.js
```

I can open `127.0.0.1:8001` now and run it. The fact that you have to `cd` into the directory is a bug in node_chat, same behavior is in OS/X.

Comment: Yeah it seems that the paths in node_chat have been hard coded. I guess i dont have too much problem with that since the listener is clearly working and i can connect to the page in the browser. As for Socket.io there are no errors being logged to the console when i call the page, so getting to the root cause of the problem is harder.